# Force Refreshing WPF Bindings (one source)

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, data-binding

I have this situation:

- A IsToolbarButtonsEnabledProperty DependencyProperties
- A have plenty of other DependencyProperties in a class (a huge class, needs to be this way)
- A serie of Buttons on a toolbar.

The `(IsEnabled)` property of each of these buttons is a function of `(IsToolbarButtonsEnabledProperty)` throught a special converter, the buttons a differenced by ConvertParameter `("PreviousButton", "NextButton"...)`

```html
  Opacity="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource OpacityBoolToIntConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                           IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DPEnableLinks, Converter={StaticResource ToolButtonEnableConverter}, ConverterParameter='ZoomOut' }"
```

`ToolButtonEnableConverter` is a converter that compares `ConverterParameter "PreviousButton"` with other value of other dependency property `(in class).` I have to many DP to make one multivalueconverter, so I read them straight from my class `((MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow;)`

**Questions**

1. When I update other DPs the value isEnabled / Opacity, dont change. How to fix this?
2. Is there a general solution to make a Binding refresh everytime a DP changes.

(Repeating myself): I will be adding more and more DPs over time, so a `MultiValueConverter` seams odd.

Answer (score 0):

One way to force the Binding to update is to create a (meaningless) property and add it to the Binding (using MultiBinding), and when you want to update your Binding you change that property, and all the Binding is updated.

I must add that the more "straightforward" way is to use MultiBinding to all the relevant properties. If  you have way to many properties that you need to bind, maybe you should re-think if you can build this functionality some other way.